# Flutter Release mode showing grey screen error but no errors showing in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is showing grey screen error when I have it running on device in release mode. In debug mode using emulator is shows no errors.

The error shows when I try to play audio file using audioplayers plugin. I have a player widget inside a player screen. Immediately after the user presses the play button, it flashes a grey screen for a moment before the audio begins playing, then the grey screen disappears, and the audio begins to play. I am using a url for the audio file which I have uploaded to a CDN.

I use the code below to create a new player screen from the app:

```
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                                          .push(
                                        CupertinoPageRoute(
                                            builder: (_) => PlayerScreen(
                                                  url: "https://linktocdnfile.m4a",
                                                  title: 'Body Scan',
                                                  name: "My name",
                                                  
                                                )),
                                      );
```

PlayerScreen

```
typedef void OnError(Exception exception);
    
Color SliderColor = Color(0xFFEDAF99);

class PlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'player_screen';
  final int? songId;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final CupertinoTabController? controller;
  final String name;
  final int? fileDuration;


  const PlayerScreen(
      {Key? key,
      this.controller,
      required this.title,
      required this.url,
      this.songId,
      required this.name, this.fileDuration})
      : super(key: key);



  @override
  _PlayerScreenState createState() => _PlayerScreenState();
}

class _PlayerScreenState extends State<PlayerScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AudioCache audioCache = AudioCache();
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _meditationStreakStream;


  final myImage = "assets/images/meditating.png";

  bool isChecked = false;

  void toggleCheckedState(bool checkBoxState) {
    setState(() {
      isChecked = checkBoxState;
    });
  }

  void callback() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  late AnimationController controller;
  late AnimationController controllerTwo;
  late AnimationController controllerThree;
  late AnimationController controllerFour;
  late AnimationController _countDownController;
  late Animation<double> animationFour;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  late Animation<double> animationTwo;
  late Animation<double> animationThree;
  late Animation<int> countDownAnimation;
  var _duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 18000);
  var _durationTwo = const Duration(milliseconds: 18500);
  var _durationThree = const Duration(milliseconds: 19000);

  

  late PlayerWidget audioWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _meditationStreakStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots();

    audioWidget = PlayerWidget(
      fileDuration: widget.fileDuration,
      title: widget.title,
      name: widget.name,
      url: widget.url,
      isChecked: isChecked,
      checkBoxCallback: toggleCheckedState,
      onPlayerFinished: () => showCupertinoModalPopup(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          dialogContext = context;
          return buildSheet(dialogContext);
        },
      ),
    );

    _countDownController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(minutes: 0));

    _countDownController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        print("THE ANIMATION HAS COMPLETED !");
      }
    });

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: _duration,
    );

    controllerTwo = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: _durationTwo,
    );

    controllerThree = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: _durationThree,
    );

    controllerFour = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: _durationThree,
    );

    animation = new Tween<double>(begin: 600.0, end: 800.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.200,
          0.800,
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        ),
      ),
    );

    animationTwo = new Tween<double>(begin: 200.0, end: 400.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controllerTwo,
        curve: Interval(
          0.200,
          0.800,
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        ),
      ),
    );

    animationThree = new Tween<double>(begin: 500.0, end: 700.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controllerThree,
        curve: Interval(
          0.200,
          0.800,
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        ),
      ),
    );

    animationFour = new Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(controllerFour);

    controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    controllerTwo.repeat(reverse: true);
    controllerThree.repeat(reverse: true);
    controllerFour.repeat(reverse: true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    controllerTwo.dispose();
    controllerThree.dispose();
    controllerFour.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> saveDuration() async {
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.durationCompleted = 1000000000001;
    activity.uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;

    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now(); //DateTime
    Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate);
    activity.dateTime = myTimeStamp;
    activity.practiceType = widget.title;
    var x = activity.durationCompleted! / 1000;
    var seconds = x % 60;

    UserService userService = new UserService();
    userService.addActivity(activity);
  }

  late BuildContext dialogContext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<Duration>.value(
              initialData: Duration(),
              value: advancedPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged),
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 250.0,
                      height: 250.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/6024852/screenshots/15565023/media/987b29bd5f82a841142900ff698e0cc3.jpg?compress=1&resize=1600x1200"),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,

                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 50),
                    child: audioWidget,

                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 280,
                  left: 50,
                  right: 50,
                  child: RichText(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: widget.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 28,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black87),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 250,
                  left: 50,
                  right: 50,
                  child: RichText(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          color: Colors.black45),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 5.0,
                  right: 5.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: new IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget buildSheet(BuildContext dialogContext) {
    final _user = Provider.of<UserListModel>(context).returnToDos;

    updatePlayerScreen() async {
      UserService userService = new UserService();
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final User? user = auth.currentUser;
      print(user);
      final uid = user!.uid;

      DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now(); //DateTime
      Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate);

      var date1 = await _user[0].lastMeditationDateTime!.toDate();
      var date2 = DateTime.now();
      var difference = date2.difference(date1).inDays;

      final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      var lastIncrementDate = await _user[0].lastIncrementDate!.toDate();
      var lastIncrementDateCheck = formatter.format(lastIncrementDate);
      var lastMeditationDateCheck = formatter.format(date1);


      userService.updateUserLastMeditationDate(
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, myTimeStamp);

      if (difference == 1 || difference == 0) {
        // and lastIncrementDateDay does not equal today
        if (lastIncrementDateCheck != lastMeditationDateCheck) {
          userService.updateUserStreak(uid, "meditations", true);
          userService.updateUserLastMeditationDate(
              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, myTimeStamp);

          //update the database
          userService.updateUserLastIncrementDate(
              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, myTimeStamp);

          //update the provider
          Provider.of<UserListModel>(context, listen: false)
              .updateUserInfo(myTimeStamp);
        }
      } else if (difference > 1) {
        userService.updateUserStreak(uid, "meditations", false);
        userService.updateUserLastMeditationDate(
            FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid, myTimeStamp);
      }
    }
    updatePlayerScreen();
    return Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.down,
      key: const Key('key'),
      onDismissed: (_) => Navigator.pop(dialogContext),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.75,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    CupertinoIcons.chevron_compact_down,
                    size: 30,
                    color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
                stream: _meditationStreakStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot.error);
                    return Text('Something went wrong');
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text('Loading'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data!.docs[0];
                  print(documentSnapshot['meditations'].toString() +
                      " THIS IS THE MEDITATION STREAK");
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Current practice streak\n\n" +
                            documentSnapshot['meditations'].toString() +
                            " days",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),

            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: Container(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: CupertinoButton(
                color: SliderColor,
                child: Text(
                  "Reflect on your practice",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  saveDuration();

                  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushReplacement(
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => ReflectionFormScreen(
                          title: widget.title + " Reflection"),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PlayerWidget

```
class PlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final PlayerMode mode;
  final bool isChecked;
  final Function checkBoxCallback;
  final VoidCallback? onPlayerFinished;
  final String name;
  final String title;
  final int? fileDuration;


  const PlayerWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.url,
        required this.title,
      this.mode = PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER,
        required this.name,
      required this.isChecked,
      required this.checkBoxCallback,
      required this.onPlayerFinished, this.fileDuration})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _PlayerWidgetState(url, mode, isChecked);
  }
}

class _PlayerWidgetState extends State<PlayerWidget> {
  String url;
  PlayerMode mode;
  bool isFinished;

  late final Function callback;

  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  late AudioCache audioCache;
  PlayerState? _audioPlayerState;
  Duration? _duration;
  Duration? _position;

  Color SliderColor = Color(0xFFEDAF99);




  bool shouldShowFirst = true;

  PlayerState _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;
  PlayingRoute _playingRouteState = PlayingRoute.SPEAKERS;
  StreamSubscription? _durationSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _positionSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerCompleteSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerErrorSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _playerStateSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<PlayerControlCommand>? _playerControlCommandSubscription;

  bool get _isPlaying => _playerState == PlayerState.PLAYING;
  bool get _isPaused => _playerState == PlayerState.PAUSED;
  String get _durationText {
    return _duration?.toString().split('.').first ?? '';
  }

  String get _positionText => _position?.toString().split('.').first ?? '';

  bool get _isPlayingThroughEarpiece =>
      _playingRouteState == PlayingRoute.EARPIECE;

  _PlayerWidgetState(this.url, this.mode, this.isFinished);


  @override
  void initState() {


    super.initState();
    _initAudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    saveDuration();
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    _audioPlayer.notificationService.clearNotification();
    _durationSubscription?.cancel();
    _positionSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerCompleteSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerErrorSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerStateSubscription?.cancel();
    _playerControlCommandSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Future<void> saveDuration() async{
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.durationCompleted = await _audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    activity.uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now(); //DateTime
    Timestamp myTimeStamp = Timestamp.fromDate(currentDate);
    activity.dateTime = myTimeStamp;
    activity.practiceType = widget.title;
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    userService.addActivity(activity);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                      activeTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                      inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                      activeTrackColor: SliderColor,
                      inactiveTrackColor: SliderColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                      trackShape: RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
                      trackHeight: 5.0,
                      thumbColor: SliderColor,
                      thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
                      overlayColor: SliderColor,
                      overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 28.0),

                    ),

                    child: Slider(
                    
                      onChanged: (v) {
                        final duration = _duration;

                        if (duration == null) {
                          return;
                        }
                        final Position = v * duration.inSeconds;
                        print(Position.toString());

                        _audioPlayer
                            .seek(Duration(seconds: Position.round()));
                      },

                      value: (_position != null &&
                          _duration != null &&
                          _position!.inMilliseconds > 0 &&
                          _position!.inMilliseconds <
                              _duration!.inMilliseconds)
                          ? _position!.inMilliseconds / _duration!.inMilliseconds
                          : 0.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              _position != null
                  ? '${_printDuration(_position!)} / ${_printDuration(_duration!)}'
                  : _duration != null
                      ? _durationText
                      : '',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                AnimatedCrossFade(
                  crossFadeState: shouldShowFirst
                      ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                      : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  firstChild: IconButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    key: const Key('play_button'),
                    onPressed: _isPlaying ? null : _play,
                    iconSize: 64.0,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    color: SliderColor,
                  ),
                  secondChild: IconButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    key: const Key('pause_button'),
                    onPressed: _isPlaying ? _pause : null,
                    iconSize: 64.0,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                    color: SliderColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // Text('State: $_audioPlayerState'),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _initAudioPlayer() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: mode);
    _durationSubscription = _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((duration) {
      setState(() => _duration = duration);

      if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
        // optional: listen for notification updates in the background
        _audioPlayer.notificationService.startHeadlessService();

        // set at least title to see the notification bar on ios.
        _audioPlayer.notificationService.setNotification(
          title: widget.title,
          artist: widget.name,
          albumTitle: 'Hello Now',
          imageUrl: 'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/c59891_e7c14f57cc2d42059734f4b44dc8426c~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_260,h_170,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/HelloNow-Logo-Stacked-Black%20(1).png',
          forwardSkipInterval: const Duration(seconds: 30), // default is 30s
          backwardSkipInterval: const Duration(seconds: 30), // default is 30s
          duration: duration,
          enableNextTrackButton: true,
          enablePreviousTrackButton: true,
        );
      }
    });

    _positionSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((p) => setState(() {
              _position = p;
            }));

    _playerCompleteSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
      _onComplete();
      widget.onPlayerFinished!();
      setState(() {
        _position = _duration;
        shouldShowFirst = !shouldShowFirst;
        // isFinished = true;
        // callback(isFinished);
      });
    });

    _playerErrorSubscription = _audioPlayer.onPlayerError.listen((msg) {
      print('audioPlayer error : $msg');
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;
        _duration = const Duration();
        _position = const Duration();
      });
    });

    _playerControlCommandSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.notificationService.onPlayerCommand.listen((command) {
      print('command: $command');
    });

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _audioPlayerState = state;
        });
      }
    });

    _audioPlayer.onNotificationPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => _audioPlayerState = state);
      }
    });

    _playingRouteState = PlayingRoute.SPEAKERS;
  }

  Future<int> _play() async {

    final playPosition = (_position != null &&
            _duration != null &&
            _position!.inMilliseconds > 0 &&
            _position!.inMilliseconds < _duration!.inMilliseconds)
        ? _position
        : null;

    _audioPlayer.play(url, position: playPosition);
    _audioPlayer.setPlaybackRate(1.0);

    final result = await _audioPlayer.play(url, position: playPosition);
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.PLAYING;
        shouldShowFirst = !shouldShowFirst;
      });
    }

    return result;
  }

  Future<int> _pause() async {
    final result = await _audioPlayer.pause();
    if (result == 1) {
    
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.PAUSED;
        shouldShowFirst = !shouldShowFirst;
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> _earpieceOrSpeakersToggle() async {
    final result = await _audioPlayer.earpieceOrSpeakersToggle();
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() => _playingRouteState = _playingRouteState.toggle());
    }
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> _stop() async {
    final result = await _audioPlayer.stop();
    if (result == 1) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED;
        _position = const Duration();
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

  void _onComplete() {
    setState(() => _playerState = PlayerState.STOPPED);
  }
}

String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
  String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
  String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
  String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
  return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: In release mode you can view errors using Logcat

Comment: Please check the errors logged while you are trying to play in debug mode. This gray screen shown in release mode because of this error. Or share the logs when you click on debug mode here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Expanded` widget should be a direct child of Row or Column. Creating an expanded widget inside StreamBuilder is a big no.

**Some Examples**

```
 Column(
  children: [

    // fine
    Expanded(flex: 2, child: Child1()),

    // fine
    Expanded(child: Text()),

    // fine, since expanded is direct child of row
    Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(),
        )
      ],
    ),

    // Bad, if expanded is used outside column and row
    AnyWidgetExpectRowOrColumn(
      child: Expanded(child: Child2()),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I get grey sections, on released apps, when I use an Expanded widget. I got my grey sections by using an Expanded widget in the title of an appbar. When I removed the expanded widget, the problem went away.

It seems that grey areas on release are an indication of an error, obviously.